# 80's (or earlier) book with gun-like weapons holstered on one's forearm, connected to their wrist nerves to jumps into their hand at will

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book in the early 80's (sometime between 81 and 83) that I have been trying to remember the title of for a long time. I got the book from my high school librarian as a reading suggestion, so it may have been a young adult book, but I don't know.

The only think I remember about the story is one of the weapons that the "good guys" wore.

The weapon was a hand gun type of weapon that they wore in a holster that was on the forearm of their gun hand.  The weapon was somehow connected to the nerves in their wrist so that when they tensed their hand or arm in a certain way the gun jumped into their hand.

Comment: This is a pretty common trope in fiction; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NothingUpMySleeve

Comment: They had weapons like that in the Deathworld series by Harry Harrison, but as @Richard says it's a fairly common idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [a comment by TheMathemagician](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51751/i-am-trying-to-figure-out-the-title-of-a-book-i-read-in-the-early-1980s#comment98680_51751), [the Deathworld series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld) has weapons like this.  In the first book, *Deathworld* (1960), there's a detailed explanation of how the guns/holsters work:

- the holster is attached to the forearm
- there are sensors that detect when the muscles of the hand/forearm are in the right position to receive the gun; there's a calibration process to set up a holster for a particular person
- a cable that becomes rigid when current is applied shoots the gun forward from the holster into the waiting hand (the character being fitted for a gun repeatedly gets his fingers mashed when he inadvertently "asks" for the gun but his hand isn't quite ready)
- the guns have no trigger guard, so that by bending their finger slightly, the person can fire the first shot as soon as the gun is in their hand

Answer (score 0):

It is *Outlanders* (first published in 1997) by Mark Ellis, the continuation of the [*Deathlands*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathlands) series by James Axler, (first published in 1986). The "heroes" you are referring to are Mags.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlanders):

> Two hundred years after a nuclear holocaust devastated the Earth, the chaos and barbarism as depicted in the 'Deathlands' series gave way to a centralized, despotic government ruled by nine mysterious barons.
>
> Material taken from redoubts, secret preholocaust military installations with stores of weapons and the home of the gateways, MAT-TRANS (matter-transfer) devices, supplied the baronial rule in what was known as the “Program of Unification.”
>
> Rearmed from redoubt stockpiles, the barons consolidated their power and reclaimed very advanced technology created two centuries before by the so-called “Totality Concept”.
>
> Their power bolstered by the invisible authority known only to an elite few as the Archons extended beyond the fortified city-states into what came to be called the Outlands. There, the rootstock of humanity survived, eking out an existence in hellzones and hounded by black-armored Magistrates, the enforcers of the barons’ laws.
>
> When Cobaltville Magistrates Kane and Grant came across a piece of misplaced technology and Brigid Baptiste, an archivist began an investigation on their behalf, they found themselves branded as sedititionists, their citizenship stripped from them and they were reclassified as Outlanders.

Comment: actually it is the continuation of the Deathlands series, it called Outlanders. The "heroes" you are referring to are Mags

Comment: Please supply some explanation as to why you think this is the answer.